# webpack sass compilation woes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webpack

I am building an application using Angular 2 (alpha.52) and webpack, but have run across a problem requiring a sass file. I have searched the www and have asked in the webpack gitter chatroom but still have the problem.

The line causing the compiler trouble goes like this:

```
var sass = require('../sass/authenty.scss');
```

but when 'npm start' builds the packages, it results in this error:

```
ERROR in Cannot find module 'source-map'
 @ ./src/app//sass/authenty.scss 4:14-141
```

I have no idea where this error is being generated. My webpack.config.js has this loader:

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass?sourceMap' }
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Add source maps as a query parameter to the css-loader and it will work, as in the configuration below:

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap' }
```

Tested successfully in my own Webpack config.

The documentation for the Webpack sass-loader is apparently no help right now. This issue and solution is documented in the blog post below and associated issue on Github:

- [Sass with Source Maps, Webpack, and Live Reload](http://ihaveabackup.net/2015/08/17/sass-with-sourcemaps-webpack-and-live-reload/)
- [Reloading extracted css with hot module replacement](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/30)